# Overlapping gnome-terminals in second monitor

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-terminal

I'm not quite sure how to properly title the issue that I'm facing.
I use a **lot** of terminals and I really like the feature where Ubuntu opens a new terminal next to existing ones.
[image: first terminal on first monitor]
[image: second terminal on first monitor]

However, If I change focus to the second monitor and try to open new terminals on the secondary monitor using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, all newer terminals spawn on top of the existing one (which is in the top left corner).

I probably sound super picky, but I would really like to find a way to get the first-monitor-behaviour on the second :(
[image: two overlapping terminals on second monitor]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The window placement is defined by the "Place Windows" Compiz plugin.

Try to change the default "smart" setting with "Pace accross all outputs".

Type in a terminal the following command to change the placement behaviour:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/place/multioutput-mode 3
```

To restore the default setting:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/place/multioutput-mode 0
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll fix this in the original post, the problem is not that its opening new windows in the wrong display. The windows are spawning in the display that has focus, but the windows overlap with each other completely.

Comment: @user1761555 I've updated my answser with a new setting value (3) which seems to avoid the problem (bug?) with terminals piling up when focus is given to the second display. Please give it a try

Comment: Does not work :(.. It gives me the same results as '0'